# How to preserve connection between One-to-One records after deletion?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

The question is a little bit tricky, so I'll try to explain it well.
At first, I have 2 entities, `Books` and `Favorites` where they are connected as One-to-One.

`Books`: `bookID`, `title`
`Favorites`: `bookID`

When I'm tapping on `favoriteButton` I execute this code:

```
let favorite = Favorites(context: context)
favorite.bookID = book.id
favorite.book = book
```

And when I want to check if the book is favorite, I do:

```
if book.favorite != nil
```

Now about the problem:

In some moments I have to delete `ALL` books and add them again, like resetting `Books` table and when I delete and add a book, it adds it with new ID(inner CoreData ID, not from the server) and thus I loose my connection between `Books` and `Favorites`, even the favorite books are still there and still keep all values.

How can I fix that problem? Can I somehow preserve that relationship between records even after deletion?
In web I would set foreign key as `bookID` and connect with it. In this case I would not loose that connection, but as CoreData connects via inner ID of records, not objects, I'm loosing my connection and cannot check `book.favorite` anymore, it returns `nil`.

I hope I could describe my problem. If not, please ask me

Comment: If you had an ordinary sql database you would face the same problem as here if you deleted all books. The problem seems more related to the logic of the program, why do you need to delete all books? If Favorites has no other attribute than bookID it would make more sense to have it as a Boolean attribute in Books. Anyway, is title a unique attribute, maybe use that as a reference instead of bookID between the two entities?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson all `bookID` are unique. I meant the separate value what I get from the server, not auto-generate IDs in DB. I'm deleting all of them because some books might be changed or even deleted from the server. That's why I'm deleting all of them, to save up-to-date data

Comment: And what is it that uniquely identifies a book you get from the server? Use that/those attributes to remember what books are favorites by adding it/them to your Favorites entity.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, I do that. But I'm also using relationships to access or check books easily if they are favorite or not, like `book.favorite != nil`. But when I delete all books and rewrite them I loose that connection. I just want to avoid each time to make selection from the database and check if it's favorite or not. I prefer to do that with foreign key

Comment: “yes, I do that.”, sorry but you lost me. What do you mean?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry! I already have a separate table where I keep `bookID`. But I also connected foreign key. I would prefer to access via foreign key instead of single-selection from DB and to check if it's favorite or not

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you want to achieve now but I don’t think this can be done automatically. I would implement a match function that was called after every delete/download that recreated the relationship between Books and Favorites objects using some attribute stored in Favorites